# Use sed to replace first line of text file on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I have a file, **cache.md**, that starts off like this:

```
# 2012-05-09.8271
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
/index.html
```

I'm trying to write a shell script (using Automator in OS X Lion) to replace the first line and change the text (after the hash) to today's date, a dot, and a random number.

Here's the bash script I have so far, but it doesn't do anything.

```
_now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
_rand=$RANDOM
sed -i '' '1 s/[\d\-\.]+/$_now.$_rand/' ~/Desktop/cache.mf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this sed command:

```
sed -i '' '1 s/^#.*$/'"# $_now.$_rand"'/' ~/Desktop/cache.mf
```

Comment: Yours was the closest and got me to a solution. I'm not wild about using .* in a regex, but using sed's one line restriction makes it safe.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you left -e off the sed expression!

I haven't checked your sed expression itself, but the base problem is you need to identify your sed expression with the -e option:

```
sed -i '' -e '1 s/[\d\-\.]+/$_now.$_rand/' ~/Desktop/cache.mf
```

Comment: Not quite right, the $_ vars won't be interpreted by the shell because they're enclosed in `'`, also the `1` at the beginning doesn't work with `#` in the input data.

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go:

```
_now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
_rand=$RANDOM
sed -i -e "s/# [0-9]\+-[0-9]\+-[0-9]\+.[0-9]\+/\# $_now.$_rand/" ~/Desktop/cache.mf
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It just creates a cache.mf-e file on my desktop, identical to the original. I have the extra '' up front because I'm on OS X Lion, which apparently has a different sed syntax from everything else.

Comment: Try this:  sed -i '' "s/# [0-9]\+-[0-9]\+-[0-9]\+.[0-9]\+/\# $_now.$_rand/" ~/Desktop/cache.mf....might need the extry ' ' up front.

Comment: Also try: sed -i '' 's/# [0-9]\+-[0-9]\+-[0-9]\+.[0-9]\+/\# $_now.$_rand/' ~/Desktop/cache.mf